# Notice: Undefined variable: conexion

Tags: php

Tengo problemas en la linea 9 de mi archivo html.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como bien dice @AlbertoSiurob en su respuesta, `$conexion` no existe porque la variable la llamaste `$link`. Si lo has corregido y te sigue dando error, muestra qué error es pulsando en [edit]  y de paso, en vez de poner una captura del código pon el texto del mismo sin más, es mucho más fácil de analizar que una imagen. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo preguntaste en otro post, lee las reglas del foro, no disturbes la integridad del sitio. 
Ahora, ya te diste cuenta que `$conexion` no existe? por eso te marca error. Entonces modifica esta línea

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db );
```

Tu error es que estás asignando la conexión de la DB a una variable `$link` y esta nunca la usas. 
Agrego que, si ya declaraste variables para los parámetros de conexión, pues úsalos.

Eso te debería solucionar el problema